# How can i join correctly on Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, join

The df join for index by default but when i try to pass a column Python give me back this error.

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(PATH + r"\foo.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel(PATH + r"\bar.xlsx")
df3 = df2.join(df1, how='outer', on='letter')
```

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

i dont wanna join by index, i need to join by a specific column

df1:

```
  letter   foo
0      A  AAAA
1      A  AAAA
2      A  AAAA
3      A  AAAA
4      B  BBBB
5      B  CCCC
6      B  DDDD
7      B  DDDD
8      C  EEEE
```

df2:

```
  letter   bar
0      A  XXXX
1      A  XXXX
2      A  XXXX
3      A  XXXX
4      A  XXXX
5      A  XXXX
6      A  XXXX
7      A  XXXX
8      B  YYYY
9      B  ZZZZ
```

i want something like this.

```
  letter   bar  foo
0      A  XXXX  AAAA
1      A  XXXX  AAAA
2      A  XXXX  AAAA
3      A  XXXX  AAAA
4      A  XXXX
5      A  XXXX
6      A  XXXX
7      A  XXXX
8      B  YYYY  BBBB  
9      B  ZZZZ  CCCC
10     B        DDDD
11     B        DDDD
12     B        EEEE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `cumcount` column (named `cc`) for each `letter` and apply  `merge` function (`outer join`) with it. and remove `cc` column after `merge`

**Code**

```
(df2
 .assign(cc=df2.groupby('letter')['bar'].cumcount())
 .merge(
     df1.assign(cc=df1.groupby('letter')['foo'].cumcount()), 
     how='outer')
 .sort_values('letter')
 .drop('cc', axis=1)
 )
```

`output`

```
    letter  bar     foo
0   A       XXXX    AAAA
1   A       XXXX    AAAA
2   A       XXXX    AAAA
3   A       XXXX    AAAA
4   A       XXXX    NaN
5   A       XXXX    NaN
6   A       XXXX    NaN
7   A       XXXX    NaN
8   B       YYYY    BBBB
9   B       ZZZZ    CCCC
10  B       NaN     DDDD
11  B       NaN     DDDD
12  C       NaN     EEEE
```

---

**Intermediate**

To help understanding, I put the code and output of the intermediate process that create `cumcount` column (named `cc`) for each `letter` in `df2`.

```
df2.assign(cc=df2.groupby('letter')['bar'].cumcount())



    letter  bar     cc
0   A       XXXX    0
1   A       XXXX    1
2   A       XXXX    2
3   A       XXXX    3
4   A       XXXX    4
5   A       XXXX    5
6   A       XXXX    6
7   A       XXXX    7
8   B       YYYY    0
9   B       ZZZZ    1
```